# NullPointerException when I add JTextField on JPanel

Tags: java, pointers, exception, nullpointerexception, jtextfield

I've a problem. take a look at this code.
I want to create a `JTextField` array, but, when I call the `add()` method, it throws a `NullPointerException`.

```
private void carregaLabels() {
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    label = new JLabel[qnt][stringLabel.length];
    cxNotaFiscal = new JTextField[qnt][stringLabel.length];
    for(int x = 0 ;x < qnt ; x++){
        for(int y = 0 ; y < stringLabel.length ; y++){          
            label[x][y] = new JLabel(stringLabel[y]) ;
            gbc.gridx = x;
            gbc.gridy = y;
            add(label[x][y],gbc);
            cxNotaFiscal[x][y] = new JTextField(20);
            add(cxNotaFiscal[x][y+1],gbc);          //<<<<the error is here !??
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Consider what happens  when `y == stringLabel.length` and you're adding 1 to it and use it to index an array. You're going out of bounds at that point.

Comment: You assign a value to element with 2nd index `y` and immediately try to access an element with `y+1` which at this point has not been initialized yet and, therefore, still `null`.

Comment: @djikay - OP would've gotten eventually an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` but he's getting `NPE` on the very first iteration.

Comment: PM 77-1 and djikay shame on me !!!

Comment: @PM77-1: Teamwork did it in the end. Your point is valid, but I think mine is too.